# PHPStorm >> Reforrmat code deletes PHP code

Tags: php, phpstorm-2016.1

I am using PHPStorm with mix HTML/PHP..

My codes are

```
<div id="tab2" class="display-none">
    <?php include_once "profile/permissions.php"; ?>
</div>
```

When I use Ctrl+Alt+L for Reformat code then PHP codes remove auto. How can I stop this.

Codes after Reformat.

```
<div id="tab2" class="display-none">

</div>
```

I can't understand PHPStorm's problem.

Comment: strange..never had such an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but problem is solved with this change...

```
<div id="tab2" class="display-none"><?php include_once "profile/permissions.php"; ?></div>
```

Just removed lines between `<?php` and `<div id="tab2" class="display-none">`

Comment: Sounds like a bug to be submitted to InteliJ